# Lumen Impersonation / temporary re-login the user

Tags: oauth, lumen, laravel-passport

I'm trying to do user's impersonation in the Lumen framework with dusterio/lumen-passport. In the UserController I have created the following method to perform re-login:

```
    public function relogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'user_id'  => 'required|integer'
        ]);

        $user = User::findOrFail($request->user_id);
        Auth::setUser($user);
        return $user;
    }
```

and re-login does not happen. If I check Auth::user(); before return then it is correctly a new user, but it is not persistent. I guess I should also force token update, but got stuck with it for hours. Any help/insights, please?

I would need not only re-login but keep the original user and therefore calling another method (e.g. loginOriginalUser) app will re-login original user.

thank you for any advice